# Running docker and 64 bit linux VM on my host windows10

Tags: docker, windows-10, ubuntu-14.04

As you all know Docker runs natively on windows 10 OS. This requires Hyper-V to be enabled. I did that and docker is running fine on my win 10. I wanted to run a 64 bit linux VM on my win 10. So I downloaded the oracle virtual box and ubuntu iso and when I opened the oracle vb it was showing only 32-bit guest versions. When I checked the online info, it recommends to turn off the Hyper-V for 64-bit guest versions to appear. I did that and was able to install the 64 bit ubuntu VM on my win 10 but it broke my docker running on win 10.

Is there any way where we can have both docker running and 64 bit virtual machine installed and running on my guest win 10 OS ??

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run Hyper-V and Virtualbox at the same time. If Hyper-V is installed on the system then VT-x is not available for VirtualBox.

I have heard of workarounds, that make switching easy, but you have to reboot the system every time.

Comment: Thanks seb. Please let me know if you get to know about the workarounds. But rebooting every time is a painful job.

Comment: Was happy with my Win7 (boot2docker VM and my 64bit ubuntu VM). Now after the upgrade to win10 it took out my happiness.

Comment: I take a look back, if i find the workaround, but in my case, is switch back to DockerTool Box (Docker on VirtualBox), i found some issues on docker for Windows (eg. mounting hostshare on others than system Drive, etc.) that make it unusable for me, for now!

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu is supported on Hyper-V](https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v). [This question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/11c1c8e0-25e6-4b0a-ad25-bfb6f02ad3c9/how-to-create-a-64bit-guest-in-hyperv-on-a-64bit-windows-server-2008-r2-ent?forum=winserverhyperv) on Microsoft forums suggests Hyper-V doesn't really care if you install a 32 bit or 64 bit OS in the virtual machine.

There are a lot of tutorials online on how to create a Hyper-V Linux virtual machine, [5 steps to create Ubuntu Hyper V Image](http://blogs.msmvps.com/punitganshani/2015/05/03/5-steps-to-create-ubuntu-hyper-v-image/) seems as good as any.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way where we can have both docker running and 64 bit virtual machine installed and running on my guest win 10 OS ??

Double-check with [VirtualBox 6.0.x](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.0) (starting Dec. 2018):

- the ten-years old ticket [4032 "[feature-request] Nested Virtualization: VT-in-VT"](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) is still active
- there is now an "[experimental feature](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/hyperv-support.html)":

> ### 2.34. Using Hyper-V with Oracle VM VirtualBox
>
> Oracle VM VirtualBox can be used on a Windows host where Hyper-V is running. This is an experimental feature.
>
> No configuration is required. Oracle VM VirtualBox detects Hyper-V automatically and uses Hyper-V as the virtualization engine for the host system. The CPU icon in the VM window status bar indicates that Hyper-V is being used.
>
> #### Note
>
> When using this feature, you might experience significant Oracle VM VirtualBox performance degradation on some host systems.